# how to take the text in an array which come from a resource?

Tags: android, string, listview, resources, switch-statement

this is a part of my code :

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
  TextView title_t = new TextView(this);
  title_t.setText("");
  String title = title_t.getText().toString();
  switch(position){



  case 0 : new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage("blah blah").setNeutralButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  }).show();
```

i want to replace the "" in the title_t.setText("") by a thing that can work.
I just want to take the title from the listview which come from a resource.
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: i have a list of item, and i want to take the title of an item and put it ine the settitle(title) . For each items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found :

```
TextView str = new TextView(this);
    str.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    String title = str.getText().toString();
```

it was the parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() i needed to find